# Socket listener not getting updates from React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I have a component in which I set my state from the passed parameters to the component

```
function ChatList({ bookingList, session, setActiveChat, setBookingList, socket }){

const [activeList, setActiveList] = useState(bookingList);
const [defaultList, setDefaultList] = useState(bookingList);
```

I set the activeList state from the passed params and then on click I update the state in order to show filtered results

```
    const changeTab = (index) => {
    if(index === 0){
        setActiveList(defaultList);
        if(defaultList.length > 0){
            setActiveChat(defaultList[0]);
        }else{
            setActiveChat(null);
        }
    }else {  
        let result = bookingList.filter(booking => booking.is_service_provider == false);
        setActiveList(result);
        if(result.length > 0){
            setActiveChat(result[0]);
        }else{
            setActiveChat(null);
        }
    }
```

So ultimately users can filter their chat lists based on the chosen index

And everything works fine, the DOM is updated and if I call the state from a regular function it shows the correct state.

But when I try to update the state from a socket listener I get the original state and not the filtered state

```
    useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('notification', (payload) => {

        let list_index = activeList.findIndex(obj => obj.id === payload.room);

        if(list_index > -1){
            let copy = [...activeList];
            copy[list_index].latest_message = payload.message;
            setActiveList(copy);
        }else{
            //Handle if user isnt in the correct segment
        }
            
    });
},[activeList])
```

The problem here is the activeList should only have 2 elements after being filtered but in the socket listener it gets the activeList with all the elements as it was before it gets filtered.

I even tested this with a random onclick listener, the onclick function gets the correct state, so why doesn't my socket listener get the updated state?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you don't clear previous listener when `activeList` changes, so there may be multiple listeners added at the same time - each with different version of `activeList` array. Could you add `console.log` to listener's body and check how many times it will be invoked after filtering?

Comment: @Aitwar Added a console.log inside the socket listener - it gets called only once as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever `activeList` changes you add a listener but you do not remove the previous handler. It might casue you

So, try using the `return` of `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
  function handler(payload) {....}

  socket.on('notification', handler);

  return () => socket.off('notification', handler);
}, [activeList]);
```

In addition when you just want to update the `activeList` the setter function gets the previous value so you can just use that, and then your effect won't need any dep other than the ref to the setter function.

```
useEffect(() => {
  function handler(payload) {
    ...
    setActiveList((prev) => {
       const index = prev.findIndex(obj => obj.id === payload.room);
       if (...) return [];
       
       return [];
    });

  }

  socket.on('notification', handler);

  return () => socket.off('notification', handler);
}, [setActiveList]);
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked beautifully. One thing that I had issues with was that the DOM was not updating after setting the new value. So I copied the prev to a new value "copy" and returned that - and now everything works.